# Why we can not access request from jsp declarations?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, request

I am new to the JSP related technologies. I faced a strange situation:
works find with scriplet

```
<%
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    if ( username != null && username.length() > 0 ) {

    }
%>
```

But with declaration request object can not be found?

[image]

I read that when be define method or variable in declarations they are part of the servlet, from the servlet we can access request object. So why is this strange behavior?

Comment: Remove the question mark (<%! )

Comment: Yes, If I remove it it becomes scriptlet. I am wondering why with declarations request object is not accessible.

Comment: Have you created a dynamic web project? (your jsp file should be inside the Web Content folder)

Comment: @dsp_user , yes the first cod snippet with scriptlet works but the second does not. The reason is that the the implicit objects are not accessible from JSP declarations.

Comment: You can declare a request variable explicitly <%! HttpServletRequest request; %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSP is converted into a servlet before compilation.

What you write inside a jsp scriptlet go inside the service() method of the servlet and everything inside jsp declaration go outside service method but inside servlet class.

if condition can only be used inside methods and request is a parameter of service method So it cannot be accessed outside service method.